# Simplification of an algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How can this fraction be simplified?
$$ \displaystyle \frac {\frac 1c+ \frac 1d}{c+d}$$
.My friend argues with my answer despite working out the answer,.Any other methods applicable

Comment: What is your answer?

Comment: Note:  "algebraic-number-theory" seems entirely random.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  Welcome!  I think you'll get a much better response if you show what you have done.  You mention your answer...show us that!  We'll certainly confirm it or point out an error.

Comment: Voting to close the question for lack of effort shown.  Please edit to show your work.

Answer (score 2):

In a fraction of fractions, you can simplify numerator with numerator and denominator with denominator:
$$\frac{\dfrac1c+\dfrac1d}{c+d}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\color{red}{c+d}}{cd}}{\color{red}{c+d}}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\leftarrow \text{ simplify}\atop{\strut }}{{\leftarrow \text{ simplify}}\atop \strut}=\frac1{cd}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

write it as:

$$
\frac{1}{c+d}\left(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} \right)
$$

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by cd: $cd\frac{\frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}}{c+ d}= \frac{d+ c}{cd(c+ d)}= \frac{1}{cd}$